# Disable open office in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, openoffice.org

When trying to start alfresco 4 community edition I am getting the following error.

```
11:23:02,512 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'OOoDirect' subsystem, ID: [OOoDirect, default] complete 
11:23:02,604 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'OOoJodconverter' subsystem, ID: [OOoJodconverter, default] 
11:23:02,645 ERROR [org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.content.JodConverterSharedInstance] [localhost-startStop-1] Unexpected error in configuring or starting the JodConverter library.The following error is shown for informational purposes only. 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: officeHome must exist and be a directory 
at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration.checkArgument(DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration.java:238) 
at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration.setOfficeHome(DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration.java:59)
```

We are not using open office, so we didn't select open office during the installation. How do we configure alfresco to ignore this check to have a clean startup log?

Comment: Can you share the openoffice/libreoffice properties from the alfresco-global.properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
jodconverter.enabled=false 
jodconverter.officeHome=null
jodconverter.portNumbers=8100
```

The configuration file: tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco-global.properties